# Not adding Listeners to instantiated objects unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to change the input of my newly created item button action but it is not adding or removing listeners.

This is my code, I am creating a new object in the inventory and the prefab has a button script attached that calls the interact Item function, I am trying to pass the item into the input for that function instead of the prefab's default item (I'm new to unity so it's probably just a dumb error lol)

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using TMPro;
    using Unity.VisualScripting;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Events;
    using UnityEngine.InputSystem.XR;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static InventoryManager Instance;
        public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
    
        public Transform ItemContent;
        public GameObject InventoryItem;

        private GameObject imageObject;
        private Image imageSlot;
        private GameObject nameObject;
        private Button button;
        private TextMeshProUGUI nameSlot;
        public interactItem interactItem;
        public UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction interactWithThisItem;
        private void Awake()
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        public void Add(Item item)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
        public void Remove(Item item)
        {
            Items.Remove(item);
        }
        public void ListItems()
        {
            foreach (Transform item in ItemContent)
            {
                Destroy(item.gameObject);
            }
            foreach (var item in Items) 
            {
                //instantiate item and declare it as obj
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(InventoryItem, ItemContent);
                button = obj.GetComponent<Button>();
                Debug.Log(interactWithThisItem);
                Debug.Log(button.onClick);
                imageObject = obj.transform.Find("PrefabItemImageSlot").gameObject;
                imageSlot = imageObject.GetComponent<Image>();
                nameObject = obj.transform.Find("PrefabItemNameSlot").gameObject;
                nameSlot = nameObject.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>();
                if (imageObject == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(":( No imageObject found ):");
                }
                if (nameObject == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(":( No nameObject found ):");
                }
                if (imageSlot == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(":( No itemSlot found ):");
                }
                if (nameSlot == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(":( No nameSlot found ):");
                }
                imageSlot.sprite = item.itemIconInput;
                nameSlot.text = item.itemNameInput;
                interactWithThisItem = () => interactItem.interactWithItem(item);
                button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
                button.onClick.AddListener(interactWithThisItem);
    
            }
            void Update()
            {
                Debug.Log(button.onClick);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have now noticed that the update function is in the wrong place and will not run every frame, however even after fixing this the problem still persists.

Comment: It would be easier if your InventoryItem had a script on it.  That script would hold all the references, and have functions (such as SetInteractItem(Item)).  This would keep things isolated, making it easier to work with and reason about.  For now try replacing the variable `interactWithThisItem` in `AddListener` with the actual anon function.

Comment: Thanks! I will add a script to the item!

Comment: I just made a variable that I update on the obj and called a function in the button that got that variable and called the interact by using that as input, so problem solved